# Fetch particular tags from HTML docs obtained after crawling and parsing using Apache Nutch 1.4

Tags: java, apache, meta-tags, nutch

I used nutch 1.4 and crawled a website.
I got the website crawled successfully and all the pages were dumped into segments.
I merged all the segments to one segment and then i used readseg command to obtain a text version of all the crawled pages.
Now I need to find out, URL of page and the meta data stored in that page.
I don't know which command to use or shall i need to do something different.

Have made a lot of efforts on google Some people said that you have to write a separate plugin for it. Can someone tell me please.

Thanks a lot :) :)

Comment: I want to fetch metadata corresponding to url of all the crawled html documents. Any help please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to do it. Sharing in case someone else needs it.
You can use index-metatags plugin provided here:
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags

It will solve this problem
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a crawling. After that enter this into terminal.

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/* output -nocontent -nofetch -nogenerate -noparse -noparsedata
```

If it runs, you will have a file with header informations plus contents in it. After that you can easily modify the file and get whatever info you want by string operations.